# c# Sqlite IsolationLevel Exception

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Did some research on this, but didn't find much on this topic.

I am writing an Import function to convert an SQLite database to SQL database.  In the CLI version it works fine, in the Web version it falls flat on its face with an isolationLevel error.  Since this is an import function it will read multiple different (same layout, version, structure; different data) sqlite databases.

The issue is when running as a Web site (multi project solution), I get 'System.Data.SQLite isolationLevel Exception'  When the CLI component (standard command line app) runs.  It reads the database correctly and continues on.

```
var connectionString = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = contract.FileRecord.FullPath(),
            ReadOnly = true
        };

var sqlHandler = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString.ConnectionString);
sqlHandler.Open();
var data = processData(sqlHandler);
sqlHandler.Close();
sqlHandler.Dispose();
```

Connection String is the absolute path to the database file.  The database file does change depending on what is used.  But the all database files have the same layout (different data).

I have tried specifying the isolation level but it still fails.

```
DefaultIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable
```

Outside of farming this work out to the CLI in its own process, is there any way to resolve the error in the Web side?

More Specifics if needed

- Multi-Project Solution
- All .Net 4.5.2 targeted
- VS2015
- The core project that has the Import functionality (And db calls) have SQLite referenced.
- The web project defines the SQL 2014 connection (working as intended)

Any ideas on how to resolve that error?  (I'd give you more on the error, but that is all I get from VS2015)

Thanks!

Comment: are you using any kind of synchronization mechanism for the method that is performing the task? have you tried to repro the issue in the CLI by generating lots of threads to call that method?

Comment: also, have you tried to implement a retry logic ({catch exception, wait a little, retry} for X times) that might mitigate the issue?